# Number combination calculating

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a task where I need to generate all possible combination of numbers from 0-0-0 to
100-100-100 (x,y,z)

```
var x = 0

var y = 0

var z = 0

while(true){
x++
while(true){
    y++
    while(true){
       z++
       msg.payload = [x,y,z]
       node.send(msg)
        }}}
```

The problem I have is that the x and y values never change (only once when input)...
I think this is not an efficient way of doing this, any suggestion?

Comment: This is not a complete code sample, but I am guessing that the issue is in msg.payload = [x,y,z]. Try this instead: let msg = {payload: [x, y, z]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of iterations it's simpler to use for loop:

```
for (let x = 0; x <= 100; ++x) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= 100; ++y) {
        for (let z = 0; z <= 100; ++z) {
            msg.payload = [x,y,z]
            node.send(msg)
        }
    }
}
```

```js
for (let x = 0; x <= 3; ++x) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= 3; ++y) {
        for (let z = 0; z <= 3; ++z) {
            // msg.payload = [x,y,z]
            // node.send(msg)
            console.log({ payload: [x, y, z] });
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you could use your while loop instead but you have to remember to break after 100 iterations:

```
let x = 0;
while(true) {
    let y = 0;
    while(true) {
        let z = 0;
        while(true) {
            msg.payload = [x,y,z]
            node.send(msg);
            if (z === 100) break;
            z++;
        }
        if (y === 100) break;
        y++;
    }
    if (x === 100) break;
    x++;
}
```

```js
let x = 0;
while(true) {
    let y = 0;
    while(true) {
        let z = 0;
        while(true) {
            // msg.payload = [x,y,z]
            // node.send(msg);
            console.log({ payload: [x, y, z] });
            if (z === 3) break;
            z++;
        }
        if (y === 3) break;
        y++;
    }
    if (x === 3) break;
    x++;
}
```

Or you use the inverted break condition for the while condition:

```
let x = 0;
while(x <= 100) {
    let y = 0;
    while(y <= 100) {
        let z = 0;
        while(z <= 100) {
            msg.payload = [x,y,z]
            node.send(msg);
            z++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

```js
let x = 0;
while(x <= 3) {
    let y = 0;
    while(y <= 3) {
        let z = 0;
        while(z <= 3) {
            // msg.payload = [x,y,z]
            // node.send(msg);
            console.log({ payload: [x, y, z] });
            z++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Probably need <= to fully resolve the question.

Comment: @CharlesBamford Yes, you're probably right. I fixed it.